# Angular 2 Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to have a input box and a button inside a popover. When i hit the button to make the popover appear it works and displays the input box and button. then the button inside the popover is meant to close it and that works. the problem is the second time i do this the input box and the button does not appear.

```
<button
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
      id="firstNameError">First Name</button>

<div id="firstNameErrorPop" class="hide">
      <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           name="firstNameErrorPop"
           #firstNameErrorPop="ngModel"
           [(ngModel)]="test"/>

           <button class="btn btn-primary maxWidth" (click)="closePopOver('firstNameError')">Save and close</button>
</div>
```

My method looks like this

```
ngOnInit(){
   jQuery("#firstNameError").popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: 'true',
        title : 'Type note below',
        content: function(){
            return jQuery('#firstNameErrorPop').removeClass('hide');
        }
    }).on('click', function(){
        //jQuery('#firstNameErrorPop').removeClass('hide');
        jQuery("#firstNameError").popover('toggle');
    });
}

closePopOver(element){
    console.log(element);
    //jQuery('#'+element+'Pop').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#'+element).popover('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular way to achieve:

```
<button (click)="showPopover = !showPopover" class="btn">Open</button>

<div *ngIf="showPopover" class="popOver">
  <input type="text">
  <button (click)="showPopover = false" class="btn">Close</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showPopover"  class="modal" (click)="showPopover = false"></div>
```

in the component class:

```
showPopover= false;
```

in your CSS

```
.modal {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      z-index: 999;
}

.popOver {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 520px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

and to show your popover with animation add this to your component decorator:

```
  animations: [
        trigger('popover', [
          transition('void => *', [
            style({ transform: 'scale3d(.3, .3, .3)' }),
            animate(100)
          ]),
          transition('* => void', [
            animate(100, style({ transform: 'scale3d(.0, .0, .0)' }))
          ])
        ])
      ]
```

and dont't forget to import:

```
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
```

to use it :

```
<div  [@popover] *ngIf="showPopover" class="popOver">
```

Comment: would that look like a pop over or a div below it.

Comment: With some plain CSS you can handle it. But if you still want to go with jquery, your code in ngOnInit() should work

Comment: *ngIf was my first choice but i ran into the problem where my ngOnInit() could not make the popover because *ngIf during false makes it so its not there for the jquery to see.